# "docker build --pull" VS "docker pull $MY_IMAGE && docker build $MY_IMAGE"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've read Docker documentation and I do not understand whether `--pull` option pulls **my image** (if it was already built before) or this option only pulls base images that I use in my Dockerfile.

My current code:

```yaml
- docker pull $MY_IMAGE
- docker build --pull --target deploy --cache-from $MY_IMAGE -t $MY_IMAGE .
```

Is calling `docker pull $MY_IMAGE` redundant if I have `--pull` in the `docker build` command?

Should my code be like:

```yaml
- docker build --pull --target deploy --cache-from $MY_IMAGE -t $MY_IMAGE .
```

?

### What is my main goal

I need to make sure that my image (that *maybe* was already built before) is available and up-to-date for further using in `--cache-from`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `docker build -t "$MY_IMAGE" .`, it will always build a new image (or reuse a cached image) and tag it with `$MY_IMAGE`.  Anything that you had previously `docker pull "$MY_IMAGE"` will lose its name (assuming it was a different image).

There's no reason to pull an old build of your image before you build a new one.

`docker build --pull` option pulls the image(s) in your Dockerfile's `FROM` line(s).  This can be useful since images like `ubuntu:20.04` or `python:3.10` do regularly get security updates and patch releases, and (assuming you have network connectivity) it's inexpensive if you already have the most recent version of the base image(s).

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, I do not need to run `docker pull $MY_IMAGE` in my case before building. But I may want to call the `pull` command if I will want to run something like `docker run`.

Comment: `docker run` will automatically pull the image if it's not present locally.  And if you've already `docker build` a local image, `docker pull` will overwrite that with the copy from your registry.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker build --pull` will always try to find the newest version of the base image. It will use your cached image and (or) your dockerfile image base image and tag.

If you use your own image for example, it will try to pull newer layers from your repository,

If you are using Ubuntu for example, it will try to use the latest or layer that's been pushed.

For your goal this purpose for what I see gives you the ability to search for new layers that might be published and pull them without specifying the current version. - keeping you up to date.

Comment: So, do I need to keep calling `docker pull $MY_IMAGE` explicitly before I run `docker build --cache-from $MY_IMAGE`?

Comment: Well, docker build --cache-from is used for a quick build, so if you building an image from an existing one, and want to also to attach yourself to the latest release or layer, I would say yes. But actually, you can also write a docker compose, that pulls, builds and pushes your images if needed.